# Software to show bubble text on image

Tags: text, images, photo-editing

I don't know if this is the right place but I am looking for a software through which I can show some comments/text on image. You know the bubble text that we show on images to describe something!?

So basically I have a home page site design on which I want to place bubble text to describe different elements. I have used such software before but don't remember its name so came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a site like this http://phrase.it/ to create speech bubbles.

Or

and if you require a software, use PhotoScape or GIMP to create speech bubbles.